# Assistance with combo box using lookup table - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, lookup-tables

Basically what I have is a `Customer` Table which contains information about our customers.  One of the fields in this table is `Customer.CustomerTypeID`.
I have a `CustomerType` Table as well that is basically a lookup table.
I want the `CustomerType.CustomerTypeName` field to populate my combo box, then when I go to save my record I want the `CustomerType.CustomerTypeID` for the `CustomerType.CustomerTypeName` I chose to be updated in the `Customer.CustomerTypeID` field.

Am I overcomplicating this?  Should I just change it so I'm storing the `CustomerName` in the `Customer` table instead of the ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

No, store the ID.

Set your combo like so:

```
Row Source: SELECT CustomerTypeID, CustomerTypeName FROM CustomerType 
Control Source : CustomerTypeID
Bound Column : 1
Column Count : 2
Column widthes : 0, 2
```

The control source + bound column means that the data will be stored to a field called CustomerTypeID in the table the form is based on, the column widths means that the ID column is hidden and the description is displayed.